# Как сделать упорядочивание по имени столбца?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
  require "includes/config.php"
?>
<?
$allPhones = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `tels`");

$deps = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT `dep` FROM `tels` ");
if( $deps ){
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($deps);
     echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Поле 1</th>
            <th>Поле 2</th>
            <th>Поле 3</th>
            <th>Поле 4</th>
            <th>Поле 5</th>
            <th>Поле 6</th>
            </tr>";
      for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($deps);
        echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0 ; $j < 7 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
 mysqli_free_result($allPhones);
}
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывел все результаты выборки, нужно сделать так, как на скрине.

Comment: ORDER BY нужно или что?

Comment: Оставить только $allPhones, добавив к тексту запроса `ORDER BY dep`. Завести переменную под предыдущее значение dep в цикле. Внутри цикла `while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($deps) )` проверяем если переменная с предыдущим значением не равна текущему - выводим шапку отдела. после чего в любом случае выводим текущую строку. После этого переменной с предыдущим значением присваиваем текущее (что бы на след. итерацию осталось)

Comment: Можете написать, как это должно выглядеть? Недавно только начал изучать PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это хороший вопрос, на его примере можно показать, что РНР умеет выаолнять множестов операций за тебя. Надо только знать нужные инструменты.

Вместо mysqli для работы с базой данных в РНР следует использовать PDO. В частности потому, что он позволит нам получить данные, уже сгруппированные по департаменту, одним запросом.

Для получения трехмерного массива, сгруппированного по определенному полю, служит метод `fetchAll()` в режиме [FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group). Для этого надо только указать желаемое поле самым первым в списке полей в запросе:

```
$phones = $pdo->query('SELECT dep, tels.* FROM tels')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

И дальше нам надо будет всего лишь вывести полученные данные с помощью двух вложенных циклов

Comment: PDO пока вообще не изучал, как это сделать ч-з mysqli? можете написать пример цикла?

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем, сделал так

```
<?php
  require "includes/config.php"
?>
<?
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=phone;charset=utf8";
$options = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options);
$phones = $pdo->query('SELECT dep, tels.* FROM tels')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
echo "<table>";
foreach ($phones as $key => $value) 
{
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td colspan='4' align='center';><strong>$key</td></strong>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$value2[name]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$value2[rank]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$value2[tel]</td>";
                        echo "<td>$value2[mail]</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
}
echo "</table>";
```